# The method second() is undefined for the type Pair

Tags: java, android, list, methods, return

I have declared a "`Pair(List(String)), (List(String))`" to receive returned data from a method. However I cannot retrieve the two separate lists because it errors saying "`The method second() is undefined for the type Pair`"

**This is my code:**

```
public class EditPeople_ListFragment extends ListFragment {

public Pair<List<String>, List<String>> ReadPeopleFile(FileReader peopleReader){
    ///Soon parsed into a string list, by delimiting and separating into two string arrays,
    char characterList[] = new char[10000]; // I'm assuming that 1000 is enough here
    int numChars = 0;
    try {
        numChars = peopleReader.read(characterList);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    String parseString = new String(characterList, 0, numChars);///Creates a string parseString.
    List<String> parseString_array = new ArrayList<String>();///Initialises a list of strings
    parseString_array = Arrays.asList(parseString.split(";"));///Splits the parseString into the parseString_array
    List <String> mobileNumber = new ArrayList<String>();///Initialises a list of strings, meant to be mobile numbers.
    List <String> name = new ArrayList<String>();///Initialises a list of string, meant to be names
    String[] parts = new String[2];
    for (String peopleDetails : parseString_array){///sets up a loop for each of the strings in parseString_array, to be split into mobile numbers, and name. 
        ///delimiter: ";" is for each peopleDetail string. Delimiter: "," separates mobile number and names in each peopleDetails string.
        parts = peopleDetails.split(",");
        mobileNumber.add(parts[0]);
        name.add(parts[1]);         


    }
    try {
        peopleReader.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    return new Pair(mobileNumber, name);
    ///Then use on return value nameList = ------.getname();
    ///and use --------.getmobileNumber();








}



public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    FileReader peopleFile_Reader = new FileReader("PartyApp_PeopleFile");
    Pair returnedpair = ReadPeopleFile(peopleFile_Reader);
    List<String> mobileList = returnedpair.first();
    List<String> nameList = returnedpair.second();





    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(inflater.getContext(), R.id.ListView_EditPeopleFragment, People_List);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
}
 }
```

Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use:

```
Pair<List<String>, List<String>> returnedpair = ReadPeopleFile(peopleFile_Reader);    
List<String> mobileList = returnedpair.first;
List<String> nameList = returnedpair.second;
```

`first` and `second` are public fields and there are no methods with such names.

Comment: Ok, that seems to work, although I have to add a cast for mobileList and nameList, to cast from Object to List<String>. Should this be happening???

Comment: See updated answer. You can declare `returnedpair` as I have done or you can cast `first` and `second` from `Object` to list

Answer (score 0):

`first` and `second` are properties for the `Pair` class not method

Comment: Ok, that seems to work, although I have to add a cast for mobileList and nameList, to cast from Object to List<String>. Should this be happening???